# Quickselect C-implementation returning unexpected values

Tags: c, implementation, selection-sort

I've implemented the following quick-select algorithm in C using pointers instead of arrays to allow for dynamic memory allocation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int random(int min, int max)
{
    return rand() % (max + 1 - min) + min;
}

int quickselect(int *a, int l, int k)
{
    int piv = *(a+random(0, l));

    int *less = malloc(sizeof(int)*l), *great = malloc(sizeof(int)*l); //allocate to the max possible size
    int l_len = 0, g_len = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= l; i++)
        if (*(a+i) < piv) 
            *(less+l_len++) = a[i]; //set "array indice" (dereferneced pointer) and increment array len
        else if (*(a+i) > piv)
            *(great+g_len++) = a[i];

    less = realloc(less, sizeof(int)*l_len); //re-allocate appropiate to the proper size
    great = realloc(great, sizeof(int)*g_len);

    if (k <= l_len)
        return quickselect(less, l_len, k);
    else if (k > l - g_len)
        return quickselect(great, g_len, k - (l - g_len));
    else
        return piv;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {5,2,6,3,7,1,0};
    printf("%d", quickselect(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a), 1));
    return 0;
}
```

When run, I'm getting unexpected values ranging from the negative millions to the positive millions. The randomness of the function makes this hard to debug. Any help?

Comment: `int piv = *(a+random(0, l));` --> `int piv = *(a+random(0, l -1));`

Comment: If that's the case, I'll just end up adding it back in (max + 1... (the change also does not seem to fix the problem :()

Comment: And `i <= l;` --> `i < l;` : These are off-by-one errors.

Comment: Thanks, those off-by-one errors were the cause. Always hard to catch those